# How can I put two elements in parallel in a JFrameMenu submenu?

Tags: java, swing, menu, parallel-processing, submenu

If I have the common `JFrameMenu` with "File","Edit","View"... let's say I want to have a sub-menu with a `JTextField` and a button to do something. How can I put both things in parallel?

The only thing I've been able to do is put them one after another or put a separator.

To explain better what I want  I've drawn this, in red what I've been able to do just adding elements to the menu and in green what I want:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: you dont need a button for any action connected with the menu. simply add an actionlistener to the menuitem

Comment: @XtremeBaumer but the JTextField will fill the menu item area so it won't be possible to press it

Comment: @ItamarGreen then add accelerator to the menuitem. also i dont think its possible to add 2 components to 1 menuitem

Comment: did you manage to fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, in fact, simply put a JPanel in the menu:

```
JTextField textField;
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
setJMenuBar(menuBar);

JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
menuBar.add(fileMenu);

JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Menu Item above");
fileMenu.add(menuItem1);

JSeparator separatorAbove = new JSeparator();
fileMenu.add(separatorAbove);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
fileMenu.add(panel);

textField = new JTextField();
panel.add(textField);
textField.setColumns(10);

JButton button = new JButton("New button");
panel.add(button);

JSeparator separatorBelow = new JSeparator();
fileMenu.add(separatorBelow);

JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Menu Item below");
fileMenu.add(menuItem2);
```

which produces this:

[image: the output]